# What was it that the "Cocoon l'Cie" summoned against Ragnarok in the Pompa Sancta Parade?

Tags: final-fantasy-xiii

During the Pompa Sancta Parade in Nautilus in Chapter 8 we see a number of familiar Final Fantasy Summons.

- Carbuncle comes out from the disk Vanille is holding
- the "Pulse l'Cie" summons Ifrit
- the "Cocoon l'Cie" summons Ramuh

when [the "Pulse l'Cie" Transforms into Ragnarok](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yLRBG09WRg0&t=2m20s) we see the "Cocoon l'Cie" summon or transform into something aswell to fight it. though i'm not sure what it is and wouldn't put it past the game to have made up something new (like with Vanille's and Sazh's Eidolon).

So i am wondering what was it the "Cocoon l'Cie" summoned against Ragnarok in the Pompa Sancta Parade?

Comment: @кяαzєя just want to request a clarification, but based on a meta discussion on [Should we have separate tags for each major Final Fantasy game?](https://anime.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1148), the accepted and active policy is "'final-fantasy' tag is still enough". If we're going to separate each series, could you write an answer on there first, is the current amount allows the separation?

Comment: The question you mention is not accepted, but is the suggested guideline in lieu of any other alternative. The policy is almost 5 years old, so it might be time to revisit this policy, as we've finally *graduated*, it's a good time to make sure our policies are scalable. At the time, FF questions were infrequent, but with the anticipation of the new FF7 remake and other games it might make sense to look at this tag and other tags such as [pokemon] and [gundam]. As we grow as a community it might be better to have more specific tagging for better context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During the parade, Cocoon l'Cie transformed into [Valefor](https://finalfantasy.fandom.com/wiki/Valefor_(summon))

> A recreation of Valefor appears at Nautilus's Pompa Sancta parade. In the play, the Cocoon l'Cie transforms into it to face Ragnarok

Valefor's first appearance as a summon was Final Fantasy X.